# What is the reason for some vulnerabilities in creating react app using npx create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx

Several months ago, there were some vulnerabilities in creating react web app, after that it corrected and were stable for months. However, today, "**12 vulnerabilities (8 low / 4 moderate)**" appears in my terminal after I **started a new react project**. Does anyone know why?

Comment: We can't help unless you show us the  12 vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vulnerabilities are found on a daily basis across several dependencies. The simple answer is that your projects are coming from some template project and there's probably not daily/frequent enough updates to that, and even if there were, there could be even more vulnerabilities found between those fixes and the time you created a new project